# How to export data from Oracle to HSQL

Tags: java, database, oracle, testing, hsqldb

I want to export data from a Oracle database to a HSQL database to use in a test environment (which doesn't have oracle).

What would be the way to proceed?

Comment: Does it have to be with Java? I'm sure Oracle provides a way to export a database, and HSQL a way to import it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ETL package using SQL Server Integration Services.

Comment: There is no mentioning of SQL Server in the question. And are you sure SSIS can connect to an embedded Java database?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, there is at least an ODBC driver. SSIS can work with many databases, it's not tied to SQL Server

Comment: I don't think HSQL supports ODBC, only JDBC.